# MEAN stack: Fetching data from mongodb and doing computations in controller file with respect to this data

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm creating a web application in MEAN stack where books are donated and other users can accept these donations. This is the [tutorial](https://github.com/michaelcheng429/meanstacktutorial) that I'm following. The details of the donations are stored in books table in the following manner:

```
{           
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55d4410544c96d6f6578f893"),
        latitude: 15.3705074,
        longitude: 75.1355679,
        "email" : "user111@gmail.com",
        "name" : "user111",
        "bookName" : "book1"
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58be6eb7e94fed1814f5757a"),
        latitude: 15.3705074,
        longitude: 75.1355679,
        "email" : "user222@gmail.com",
        "name" : "user222",
        "bookName" : "book2"
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58be6a37e94fed1814f57579"),
        latitude: 15.3705074,
        longitude: 75.1355679,
        "email" : "user333@gmail.com",
        "name" : "user333",
        "bookName" : "book3"
    }
}
```

This is my controller file:

```
angular.module('showApp', []).controller('AppCtrl',['$scope','$timeout','$http', function($scope , $timeout, $http) {
 $scope.getDonations = function(curLong, curLat){
            $http.get('/books/').success(function(response){
                $scope.books = response;
                $scope.x = "";
    //how can I calculate distance here using latitude and longitude from books table and display on the webpage?
            });
        };
}]);
```

The current location of the user are passed to the getDonations function. I'm having trouble in calculating the distance. I need to calculate the distance between the current user and the locations in every entry of books table and display the distance on the angular webpage so that the user can see the distance of the donations from his loaction.

angular code:`

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td>Book Name</td>
        <td>Donor's name</td>
        <td>Email ID</td>
        <td>Distamce</td>
    </tr>                               
    <tr ng-repeat="x in books">
        <td>{{x.bookName}}</td>
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.email}}</td>
        <td>  </td> //I need to display the distance here
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please help me figure out how to do this. Thankyou :).

Comment: Have you searched on Github or npm for a node module that calculates distance between 2 long/lat points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you need to know the user's current location.  If you have it--
 great.  Otherwise you can rely on [HTML geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation).  You then need to calculate the distance between these two points.  [Here is an example.](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

So let's assume we are using HTML5 geolocation...

```
function degToRad(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

function distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
  // from http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
  var R = 6371; // kilometers
  var φ1 = degToRad(lat1);
  var φ2 = degToRad(lat2);
  var Δφ = degToRad(lat2-lat1);
  var Δλ = degToRad(lon2-lon1);

  var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
    Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
    Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

  var d = R * c;
  return d;
}

function success(position) {
  var userLat  = position.coords.latitude;
  var userLong = position.coords.longitude;

  $scope.books = response.map(function (book) {
    book.distanceFromUser = distance(userLong, userLat, book.longitude, book.latitude)l
    return book;
  });
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, function error () { 
  // do something....
});
```

Comment: Thankyou so much this worked! what will be R's value if i want the distance in kilometers?

Comment: R is the radius of the earth.  R=6371 should give answer in km